# broken dependencies are not solved

Tags: apt, dependencies, error-handling, tftp

When i installed the

```
sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server tftpd-hpa syslinux nfs-kernel-server initramfs-tools
```

I got error. after that i wanted to fix the broken dependencies problem i tried

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-common setools
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools nfs-common rpcbind
Suggested packages:
  open-iscsi watchdog
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools nfs-common rpcbind
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 591 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/258 kB of archives.
After this operation, 857 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 210379 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../initramfs-tools_0.103ubuntu4.2_all.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools_0.103ubuntu4.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../rpcbind_0.2.1-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/rpcbind_0.2.1-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../nfs-common_1%3a1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nfs-common_1%3a1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools_0.103ubuntu4.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/rpcbind_0.2.1-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nfs-common_1%3a1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if the location containing the script (in this example, /var) has been mounted with the `noexec` option. You can confirm this by running `mount`. If so, modify /etc/fstab and re-mount appropriately.

Comment: i restarted the system it solved my problem anyway thanks.

Comment: but I want to know more about apt-get in depth concepts and debugging could you recommend any sites or books.

Comment: The errors you received were from dpkg (which is invoked by apt-get) - dpkg reported the error that it was unable to run the installation script it attempted to execute due to permission being denied. Assuming that the package had appropriate permissions set for each file, the next place that the execute permission could have been denied would be the filesystem.  `dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied`

Comment: For a concise primer, [this one](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/12/concise-apt-get-dpkg-primer-for-new.html "Apt-get / Dpkg primer") does an adequate job